# Is it safe to run WindowsXP as a Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-xp, security, virtual-machine

I know XP should not be used on a normal internet-facing PC. But if you run it within a sand-boxed VM that can't access the main PC, is that OK?

My use-case is I run a VPN within a VM, to RDP into a remote PC I work on. I do it through a VM so the VPN only affects that RDP so my regular web usage doesn't get routed through their network.

I have lots of XP licenses - and XP Mode in W7 - and none spare for other Windows versions. So I wondered if the XP VM is only used for RDP access, if this is 'safe' even if the OS did somehow get compromised (unlikely as I never browse the web from the VM)?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. I have a VM that I run XP in for programs/games that won't run on newer OS's. I run mine with an anti-virus and I've never had any issues with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows XP Mode Vulnerabilities as of April 8th, 2014](http://superuser.com/questions/666524/windows-xp-mode-vulnerabilities-as-of-april-8th-2014)

Comment: XP won't be any safer just because it's in a VM, but it (shouldn't) be able to touch your host OS.

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe for your host OS as XP will run in a sandbox so anything that happens will stay there but the guest OS would be vulnerable to attacks so always try to keep an antivirus running in the guest os just in case